# Constructing small Kretschmann Surface plasmon set up

Tags: manufacturing-engineering, optics

I am trying to build a SPR setup at home which is based off this diagram:

[image]

I wanted to try to miniaturize it and had some concerns about my strategy.

So I was thinking I could buy a big prism and maybe use a glass cutter tool from amazon to slice it cross-section wise to make it smaller. Although I am uncertain of this strategy or if there is a better method. As for the laser, I can find small lasers on amazon, but I was wondering which manufacturers could build me a laser smaller than the size of something like a finger nail or even smaller?

Comment: I was peripherally involved in feeding microscopic samples onto a commercial SPR device, where the client was manufacturing some kind of biomolecular assay. Can't speak for the optics but my impression was that even when working properly, which was not a given, it was extremely touchy and hypersensitive to disturbances. Seems hard for homebrew // just buy a prism (and all the optics) from Thorlabs or similar. // I think you would have to bond it to the surface coating too